# T-SQL: How to find if a column exists in a list of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

My goal is to get a list of tables from a stored procedure and then return the name of those tables along with their row count and if a `ModifiedDate` column exists in each table.

So far it almost works but this current code gives me back a few tables where it says `ModifiedDate` both exists and doesn't exist. I'm guessing the problem lies in that last select statement.

```
-- Create temporary table
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
  [object_name] NVARCHAR(255) ,
  [object_id] NVARCHAR(255),
  [row_count] INT
)

-- Insert table names, object id and row count into temp table
INSERT  INTO #TempTable
    SELECT DISTINCT
            [object_name] = SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '.' + o.name ,
            o.object_id,
            ddps.row_count
    FROM    sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.spMyStoredProcedure',
                                           'OBJECT') d
            JOIN sys.objects o ON d.referenced_id = o.[object_id]
            INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON i.object_id = o.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ddps ON i.object_id = ddps.object_id
                                                          AND i.index_id = ddps.index_id
    WHERE   o.[type] IN ( 'U', 'V' )
            AND i.index_id < 2
            AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0;

-- Join temp table to query that searches for a ModifiedDate column
SELECT  DISTINCT t2.[object_name] AS 'TableName' ,
    t2.[row_count] AS 'RowCount' ,
    CASE
        WHEN t1.name ='modifiedDate' THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN t1.name <> 'modifiedDate' THEN 'No'
    END AS 'ModifiedDateExists'
FROM    sys.columns AS t1
    RIGHT JOIN #TempTable AS t2 ON t1.object_id = t2.object_id;

-- Delete temp table
IF ( OBJECT_ID('mydbhere..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TempTable
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `sys.columns` will contain multiple records for 1 object (table) (one for each column).  You need a 1-1 relationship there. The distinct you're using is hiding the fact that you'd have *a lot* more rows (1 for each field in fact).

So you need to ensure only 1 record is returned from the join between `sys.columns` and `#TempTable`.  This can be done by only searching for `modifiedDate` and allowing the existing of a NULL on your right join to mean that it doesn't exit.

```
SELECT  t2.[object_name] AS 'TableName' 
     ,  t2.[row_count] AS 'RowCount' 
     , case when t1.name is not null then 'YES' else 'No' as 'ModifiedDateExists'
FROM sys.columns AS t1
RIGHT JOIN #TempTable AS t2 
  ON t1.object_id = t2.object_id
 and t1.name ='modifiedDate'
```

Since SQL server will prevent the same named object (column/field) from being in a table, simply limit to just that column; all other records would result in a Null, and then in our case statement we can say yes or no.

All the tables in `#tempTable` will be returned but only 1 column.

A general rule of thumb is to avoid Distinct unless you *really* mean it as it generally is just hiding a problem on a join, limit or something.